# SYSCALL and SYSRET Developer Setup

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-64, system-calls

Am I correct in understanding that `syscall` relates to some register or block of memory that contains a jump table which can be setup by the kernel developer? And then `sysret` just returns you to the application code where `syscall` was executed.

If so, where can I learn more about how to setup this register/memblock/table?

Comment: The `syscall` instruction on its own does not make use of any jump table.  It just transfers control to some configurable address in kernel space.  However, a jump table is commonly used by code at that address to then select a system call handler to use.  Refer to the Intel Software Development Manuals for details and documentation.

Comment: @fuz To clarify my understanding based on your response. `syscall` jumps to a known address in space reserved for kernel developers (kernel space). From there, the arguments passed into specific registers are used as needed for accomplishing tasks. Then `sysret` just returns you from this reserved kernel space, to the application calling site.

Comment: Correct.  Note that the address `syscall` jumps to can be configured through some special registers.  The `syscall` instruction also does some other things; read the Software Development Manuals instead of guessing.  They are the original source of truth in this regard.

Comment: re: jump tables to handle system calls once control is transferred to your kernel's syscall entry point, see [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731) for a walk-through of how Linux does it.  (Or did before KPTI mitigation for Spectre / Meltdown.)  The actual behaviour of `syscall` itself is configured by two MSRs.